# SQL Server - empty columns after insert data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a very weird problem. I have a table `A` with a few columns:

```
test1 varchar(10) not null
test2 varchar(8) not null
test3 varchar(7) not null
test4 as test2 + test3 PERSISTED NOT NULL
```

When I try to insert values, just the first value inserts into the first column, but all other columns remain empty.

```
INSERT INTO A (test1, test2, test3) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Why does this happen?

**UPDATE:** Sorry but colleague forgot to update me that the problem is in our software and not with the SQL.

Comment: What is the error message and what values are you inserting?

Comment: Can you please share a repro

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to insert values just the first value insert to first
>   column and the another doesn't insert.

You have constrain on  test2/test3/test4 - NOT NULL 
if you wont insert only fist column test1 set default values

```
test2 varchar(8) not null DEFAULT ''
test3 varchar(7) not null DEFAULT ''
```